# Hide some applications from other users

Tags: macos, applications, sharing, user-account

I need to make use of a beta version of Xcode and so I created a second account on my machine, account B. I wish to install the beta Xcode onto account B such that account A is not able to see this application, e.g. through the open with menu, or the launchpad. Is this possible? It seems like applications are visible from all accounts whether in the Applications folder of the original user or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, apps in /Applications are shared with all users. The standard location for apps that you only want a certain user to see is ~/Applications. You may need to create this folder if it doesn't exist—it will automatically get an icon.

Comment: True in general, don't know whether it will work for Xcode due to dependencies with iTunes etc.

Comment: In Account B, i have created a folder called privateApps (could be anywhere else). I edited the sharing permissions of the folder and its contents- only gave account B read and write permissions. Was just a test. So far account A does not see the apps within that folder. I will test with more apps when i  get the chance